# Mongodb compass keeps on showing activating plugin

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-compass

When I open my MongoDB compass it keeps on showing loading, My os is windows 10, Please help me to sort out the issue

Comment: Please get the latest version of MongoDB from the official website and then install the latest version of compass by using the ```install_compass``` binary.

Comment: Or download it directly from the main site https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass.

Answer (score 11):

you can just add this path to your path

```
C:\Windows\System32\wbem
```

this works for me. I'm using win7

Comment: Works for Windows 10 also!

Comment: woked, add this to Environment Variable

Answer (score 5):

I was having he same issue. I solved this by adding this:
Go to This PC-> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Vaiable -> System Variable -> Path -> New -> C:\Windows\System32\wbem(Copy and Paste this path).
Hope this helps. Upvote and mark this as an answer if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Open environment variables settings and add **C:\Windows\System32\wbem** to path variable.
[image: Add Path Variable]

Answer (score 1):

I'm also have this same issue -- I did a new download/install of 1.21.2 and it did not help. I did notice a "migrating" phase I don't recall seeing before. I had not expressly attempted an upgrade (I can be wrong, maybe I did, but I don't recall doing it). I suspect that something has gone wrong with this recent version... I did have these in my PATH:

%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;

Answer (score 1):

Try with the Isolated Version. It helped me:

https://github.com/mongodb-js/compass/releases/download/v1.21.1/mongodb-compass-isolated-1.21.1-win32-x64.msi